# Using jq, convert array of name/value pairs to object with named keys

Tags: json, object, key, command-line-interface, jq

Given a json file in the format as :

```
[
  {
    "name" : "A",
    "value" : "4"
  },
  {
    "name" : "B",
    "value" : "2"
  },
  {
    "name" : "C",
    "value" : {
      "X": "Something",
      "Y": "Else"
    }
  }
]
```

How would I convert it to something like this using jq:

```
{
  "A": "4",
  "B": "2",
  "C": {
    "X": "Something",
    "Y": "Else"
  }
}
```

I did come close using `jq 'map( { (.name): .value } )` but that still leaves each object in its separate braces instead of having them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be the exact use case for `from_entries`

```bash
$ echo '[
  {
    "name" : "A",
    "value" : "4"
  },
  {
    "name" : "B",
    "value" : "2"
  },
  {
    "name" : "C",
    "value" : {
      "X": "Something",
      "Y": "Else"
    }
  }
]' | jq 'from_entries'
```

```json
{
  "A": "4",
  "B": "2",
  "C": {
    "X": "Something",
    "Y": "Else"
  }
}
```

See: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries (linking to `1.6` because it's the latest at the time of this writing, but `from_entries` has been available at least since `1.2`.)

In case you noticed `from_entries` already but thought it wouldn't work because your data has `name` instead of `key`, note this quote from the docs (linked above):

> `from_entries` accepts key, Key, name, Name, value and Value as keys.

So `name` works just fine, here.

If the use of `key` is acceptable, then (using `to_entries`) the reverse works also:

```bash
echo '{
  "A": "4",
  "B": "2",
  "C": {
    "X": "Something",
    "Y": "Else"
  }
}' | jq 'to_entries'
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": "A",
    "value": "4"
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "key": "C",
    "value": {
      "X": "Something",
      "Y": "Else"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 9):

Using your approach, simply add `add` to your filter:

```
map( { (.name): .value } ) | add
```