# jq convert named array to list

Tags: json, jq

How to take the names of the named array, insert them as elements into it, then remove the name?

```json
{
  "l1": {
    "v1": {
      "a": [1],
      "b": [2]
    },
    "v2": {
      "a": [3],
      "b": [4]
    }
  },
  "l2": {
    "v3": {
      "a": [5],
      "b": [6]
    },
    "v4": {
      "a": [7],
      "b": [8]
    }
  }
}
```

into

```json
[
  {
    "id": ["l1"],
    "v1": {
      "a": [1],
      "b": [2]
    },
    "v2": {
      "a": [3],
      "b": [4]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": ["l2"],
    "v3": {
      "a": [5],
      "b": [6]
    },
    "v4": {
      "a": [7],
      "b": [8]
    }
  }
]
```

The names (`"l1"`, `"l2"`) are not known a priori, nor are the other contents; all I know is that I want to take the top-level names and insert them as `"id"`-named objects.

I believe this is close to opposite [Using jq, convert array of name/value pairs to object with named keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52303570).

```
jq 'to_entries'
```

starts, but embeds both `"key"` and `"value"`, whereas I really just want to add (prepend) `"key"`, even better controlling the literal "key" to (say) `"id"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track thinking of `to_entries`:

```
[to_entries[] | {id: .key} + .value]
```

Nuf said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that works. One optimization you can do on top of this to use map instead of for in. But this just works

```js
let sourceArr = {
  "l1": {
    "v1": {
      "a": [1],
      "b": [2]
    },
    "v2": {
      "a": [3],
      "b": [4]
    }
  },
  "l2": {
    "v3": {
      "a": [5],
      "b": [6]
    },
    "v4": {
      "a": [7],
      "b": [8]
    }
  }
};

let targetArr = [];

for( let id in sourceArr ){
   let obj = {
       "id": id
   }
   
   let subItem = sourceArr[id];
   //let itemKey = Object.keys(mainItem);
   for( item in subItem ){
      let itemKey = item;
      let itemVal = subItem[item]
      
      let subItems = {};
      subItems[itemKey] = itemVal;
      Object.assign(obj, subItems);
   }
   
   targetArr.push( obj );
   
}

console.log( targetArr );
```

Comment: Yes javascript :-) no problem