# How to transform existing JSON data to get rid of the useless field?

Tags: json, linux

I have JSON data I got by using `lscpu` Linux command with the `-J` flag.
It outputs array with elements with such format:

```json
{"field":"fieldName", "data":"information"}
```

How can I change its format to

```json
{"fieldName":"information"}
```

using `lscpu` either `jq`?

I tried to make it via script, but I think there'd be prettier way.

**Example**

A more detailed example output from `lscpu --json`

```json
{
   "lscpu": [
      {"field": "Architecture:", "data": "x86_64"},
      {"field": "CPU op-mode(s):", "data": "32-bit, 64-bit"},
      {"field": "Byte Order:", "data": "Little Endian"},
... omitted lines
      {"field": "Flags:", "data": "fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves avx512vbmi umip avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq la57 rdpid fsrm arch_capabilities"}
   ]
}
```

Comment: `jq` is the correct tool to use. Please show what you tried.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303570/using-jq-convert-array-of-name-value-pairs-to-object-with-named-keys for a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I've searched for is used in `lscpu` Linux command, so the final version would be

```bash
lscpu -J | jq '.lscpu | map( { (.field): .data } ) | add'
```

resulting into the required output of, in example

```json
{
  "Architecture:": "x86_64",
  "CPU op-mode(s):": "32-bit, 64-bit",
  "Byte Order:": "Little Endian",
... omitted lines
  "Flags:": "fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves avx512vbmi umip avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq la57 rdpid fsrm arch_capabilities"
}
```

Comment: Not all Linux system will have a `lscpu` version installed where the switch `-J | --json` is available, see "old" [`man lscpu`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lscpu) vs. [Ubuntu Bionic `man lscpu`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/lscpu.1.html), or RHEL 7 output of `lscpu -J` which is `lscpu: unrecognized option --json`.

Comment: @U880D The question is predicated on getting JSON output from `lscpu`, and is just about how to reformat it.

Comment: @U880D You mean there're Linux distros which wouldn't get necessary lscpu mechanic neither if lscpu would be updated?